# Group by +- 30 minutes relative the current datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have duplicates in the table and have to remove them.

Why? User can click "Save" or "Save and Close" buttons and because was an error there are clones of record when he clicked the "Save" button several times. Typical sityation.

User can add duplicates in the table but not often than one per hour, session with window about 30 minutes.

Other words - we should remove records which were created in +- 30 minutes time period.

I need help, can I solve my task without loops (cursors)?

My attempts and example data:

```
declare @testData table(id int, createdOn datetime, val varchar(20))

insert into @testData(id, createdOn, val)
select 1, '2018-06-01 14:00:00' as CreatedOn, 'value1' as value1
union select 2, '2018-06-01 14:02:00', 'value1'  -- duplicate
union select 3, '2018-06-01 14:04:00', 'value1'  -- duplicate
union select 4, '2018-06-01 15:00:00', 'value2'
union select 5, '2018-06-01 15:02:00', 'value2'  -- duplicate
union select 6, '2018-06-01 15:03:00', 'valueUniq1'
union select 7, '2018-06-01 15:04:00', 'valueUniq2'
union select 8, '2018-06-01 15:40:00', 'value2'
union select 9, '2018-06-01 15:41:00', 'valueUniq3'
union select 10, '2018-06-01 15:59:00', 'value1'  -- NOT DUPLICATE!!!
union select 11, '2018-06-01 16:05:00', 'value1'  -- duplicate

-- Option 1

;
with duplicates(IdDup, CreatedOnDup, valueDup)
as (
    select a.Id, a.CreatedOn, a.val
    from @testData a, @testData b
    where a.id <> b.id
        and a.val = b.val
        and a.CreatedOn between dateadd(minute, -30, b.CreatedOn) and dateadd(minute, 30, b.CreatedOn)
)
select * from @testData
where Id in (
    select IdDup
    from duplicates)
and Id not in (
    select min(IdDup)
    from duplicates
    group by valueDup)

-- Option 2

;
with duplicates(CounterDup, IdDup)
as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        Partition By 
            a.val
            , cast(a.CreatedOn as date)  -- Incorrect, must be +- 30 minutes, not the whole day
        Order By a.Id ASC) As counterDup
        , a.Id as idDup
    from @testData a, @testData b
    where a.id <> b.id
        and a.val = b.val
        and a.CreatedOn between dateadd(minute, -30, b.CreatedOn) and dateadd(minute, 30, b.CreatedOn)
    )
select * from @testData
where Id in (
    select IdDup
    from duplicates
    where CounterDup > 1)
and Id not in (
    select IdDup
    from duplicates
    where CounterDup = 1)
```

Both approaches return the same results, rows to delete(duplicates):

```
2 2018-06-01 14:02:00.000   value1
3 2018-06-01 14:04:00.000   value1
5 2018-06-01 15:02:00.000   value2
10 2018-06-01 15:59:00.000  value1
11 2018-06-01 16:05:00.000  value1
```

The penultimate row must not be in the resultset.

```
10  2018-06-01 15:59:00.000 value1
```

This is not duplicate, it is a new session, because > 30 minutes after previous "value1".

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? If 2012+ this is pretty simple.

Comment: MS SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage LAG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 with a partition here for this. This will return those that are duplicate by the rules you stated you want. I used a cte and added a couple of columns so you can visualize what is going on there.

```
with MyCte as
(
    select *
        , LagResult = LAG(createdon, 1) over(partition by val order by createdon)
        , IsNewSession = case when datediff(minute, createdon, LAG(createdon, 1) over(partition by val order by createdon)) < -30 then 1 else 0 end
    from @testData
)
select *
from MyCte
where IsNewSession = 0
    and LagResult is not null
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me very much! I didn't know about LAG absolutely. Works fine!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to try without lag you can use this query for prior ver of SQL

```
 Select * into  #tmp from 
(Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by val order by createdOn) valorder ,* 
 from @testData 
) t


Select * from #tmp a
inner join #tmp b on a.id = (b.id + 1) and a.val = b.val
where DATEDIFF(mi, b.CreatedOn, a.CreatedOn) <=30

drop table #tmp;
```

Comment: Incredible. You are right too. But I think, that first option more universal and flexible. But speed may be better in your solution.
I found one typo in your code: must be "valorder" instead "id" in the second select.

Comment: thanks Pavel! I agree that first option is better.This query digs more into the logic that is wrapped in the LAG function .It will be helpful to understand the logic and will work for versions prior to 2012.I just created this for better understanding.